# Creating a container in azure exits the method

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, azure-container-instances

I'm learning Azure storage development and I'm trying to create a container and then upload a file to it. I created a console app and am calling the upload method from Main.  Here is the first half of the upload method that creates the container.

```
       public async static Task<bool> UploadToAzure()
        {
            string containerName = "sample-"+Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            var connectionString = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
            
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

            try
            {
                var test = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainers();
                foreach (var container in test)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(container.Name);
                }

                var result = await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.PublicAccessType.BlobContainer);
                var containerProp = await containerClient.GetPropertiesAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(containerProp.Value);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine(ex.Message+"\n}");
            }
```

I started with just calling the `containerclient.CreateIfNotExistsAnsync()` and it wouldn't create the container.  On a whim, I added the `blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainers()` and now it will create the container.  I can comment out `blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainers()` and it will not create the container.  I can put it after the create method and it still won't work.  That's the first issue.

The second one is, it exits the code when inside the `containerclient.CreateIfNotExistsAnsync()` method.  It will create the folder but never hit the next line of code.  I get a message in the console that it "exited with code 0.  Press any key to close this window...".  It doesn't hit the Catch or display any kind of error, it just exists.

I got this pattern from my Udemy course and I've read a number of articles online and these seem to be the right steps.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from our end, The code you were using was working for us until we found that you have missed using await while calling `UploadToAzure()`.

Below is the code that we used

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await UploadToAzure();
        }
        public async static Task<bool> UploadToAzure()
        {
            string containerName = "sample-" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            var connectionString = "<YOUR_COONECTION_STRING>";
            var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);

            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.PublicAccessType.BlobContainer);

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

else you can completely remove async and have

```
namespace CreateContainer
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            UploadToAzure();
        }
        public static bool UploadToAzure()
        {
            string containerName = "sample-" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            var connectionString = "<YOUR_COONECTION_STRING>";
            var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);

            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            containerClient.CreateIfNotExists(Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.PublicAccessType.BlobContainer);

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** It is preferable to use the async method since you might face some issues if you are dealing with large volumes of data.

Comment: Perfect!  That was the issue.  Thank you!